# Why my events don't fire in a service?

Tags: c#, service, event-handling, naudio

I made a windows form application that listens from the microphone and detects sound patrons.

Now i want to do the same but in a service.

I use Naudio and this event:

```
myWave = new WaveIn();
...
myWave.DataAvailable += new EventHandler<WaveInEventArgs>(myWave_DataAvailable);
```

At windows form works fine, but the service don't fires the event.

Does anyone know why?

Another question is

Will my service hear the microphone even when not logged in?

Thanks!

**Edited with new information and using WaveInEvent class:**

I declare the variable in the class

```
public partial class SoundDetector : ServiceBase {
    ... 
    private WaveInEvent myWave;
```

Set the event in the constructor

```
public SoundDetector()
{
    myWave.DataAvailable += myWave_DataAvailable;
```

And start recordig in the OnStart

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    myWave.StartRecording();
```

But the event still stop firing...

Comment: Never seen NAudio before, but a quick look at the source seems to indicate that it's using window messages - that's not going to work well since the service won't have a message loop running.

Comment: Are you talking about a Windows Service, right?

Comment: Yes, a Windows Service.

I'm trying to find another way to handle the events from wavein with 

using (WaveIn myWave = new WaveIn(WaveCallbackInfo.FunctionCallback()))
            {

}

Now the event fires three times but then stops...

Comment: I updated the naudio library to the 1.5.10 version, and now i use WaveInEvent instead of WaveIn, but the event only fires a couple of times and then... nothing.

Comment: When something works for a short while and then stops, I usually find it's because something that you should be keeping a long term reference to has only been stored in a local variable, and then the garbage collector has come along and finalized it, wiping it out. Could that be the case here? (The storage may be direct or transitive - e.g. you might be storing the reference into a field of a class, but then not keeping any reference to the class instance stored)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, I edited my question with some code. I'm, unable to find my mistake...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `WaveInEvent` class instead

Comment: I'm already using WaveInEvent class, but the DataAvailable event stops firing at few seconds from start...

Comment: Is the RecordingStopped event firing, and if so, does it have an Exception property?

Comment: As expected, it was my fault.

Effectively RecordingStopped event was triggered with one exception.
I made a function to write a log in a txt file and there was a conflict in accessing the file...

Thanks for your help, because I could not see it.